# Can't access github or spotify on Fedora

Tags: github, spotify, fedora

I'm pretty much a beginner in Fedora and Linux in general so I am pretty confused as to why this is happening. When I was at University everything worked fine, but after moving back home I'm not able to access Github or Spotify. When trying to push changes I keep getting the "unable to resolve host: github.com" error message, and when accessing Github.com or Spotify I get the issues attached in the screenshots.

I would love to provide more information but I'm not sure what I could add. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Github.com error]

[image: Spotify error]

Comment: It is ridiculous, i am having the same issue. If I connect through my mobile phone as modem, It works, but through my ethernet or wifi it doesn't work. 

It must be fedora. But who can help with this issue?